why event datagridview RowPostPaint output image in row header becomes blurry in vb.net
I'm Trying to use event datagridview RowPostPaint but output image in row header becomes blurry and there is a white color on each side of the in image with vb.net.
If you look at the screenhot, the result of a good image appears in the picturebox, how can I have the same result as the picturebox. Or something is wrong with my code.
Please Guide me
Thanks
Public Class Form1

    Private _source As New BindingSource()
    Private _person As List(Of person) = Nothing

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        _person = New List(Of person)()
        _person.Add(New person With {
            .ID = 1,
            .Name = "Tridip"
        })
        _person.Add(New person With {
            .ID = 2,
            .Name = "Sujit"
        })
        _person.Add(New person With {
            .ID = 3,
            .Name = "Arijit"
        })
        _source.DataSource = _person
        DataGridView1.DataSource = _source

    End Sub
    Private Sub DataGridView1_RowPostPaint(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowPostPaint
        'Convert the image to icon, in order to load it in the row header column
        Dim myBitmap As New Bitmap(imageList1.Images(0))
        Dim myIcon As Icon = Icon.FromHandle(myBitmap.GetHicon())

        Dim graphics As Graphics = e.Graphics

        'Set Image dimension - User's choice
        Dim iconHeight As Integer = 20
        Dim iconWidth As Integer = 20

        'Set x/y position - As the center of the RowHeaderCell
        Dim xPosition As Integer = e.RowBounds.X + (DataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth / 2)
        Dim yPosition As Integer = e.RowBounds.Y + ((DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Height - iconHeight) \ 2)

        Dim rectangle As New Rectangle(xPosition, yPosition, iconWidth, iconHeight)
        graphics.DrawIcon(myIcon, rectangle)

    End Sub
End Class


Public Class person
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
End Class





update code
Private Sub DataGridView1_RowPostPaint(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowPostPaint
        'Convert the image to icon, in order to load it in the row header column
        Dim myBitmap As New Bitmap(imageList1.Images(0))
        Dim myIcon As Icon = Icon.FromHandle(myBitmap.GetHicon())

        Dim graphics As Graphics = e.Graphics

        'Set Image dimension - User's choice
        Dim iconHeight As Integer = 20
        Dim iconWidth As Integer = 20

        'Set x/y position - As the center of the RowHeaderCell
        Dim xPosition As Integer = e.RowBounds.X + (DataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth / 2)
        Dim yPosition As Integer = e.RowBounds.Y + ((DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Height - iconHeight) \ 2)

        Dim rectangle As New Rectangle(xPosition, yPosition, iconWidth, iconHeight)
        'graphics.DrawIcon(myIcon, rectangle)
        graphics.DrawImage(myBitmap, rectangle)
    End Sub


result from update code

result answer from @dr.null


Get rid of the Icon conversion and just draw the Bitmap.

@jmcilhinney , I've tried but still blurry

If you have changed the code then you need to update the question, either adding or substituting the new code. We can't know whether you've done it properly if we can't see how you've done it.

@jmcilhinney , sorry, I've updated the code in the post and also screenhot

The new screenshot does look better than the old one, but obviously still not great. It appears to be the result of resizing the image. It would be a good idea to use an image that isn't bigger than what you want to draw, if at all possible. Assuming that's not possible, you might experiment with the InterpolationMode property of the Graphics object and see if that can clean things up a bit. If you're starting with a small image and resizing it just a little bit, you may not be able to generate a result that isn't messy to some degree.

Set Image dimension - User's choice What does this mean and how?

@dr.null , sorry I replied late. Set Image dimension - User's choice What does this mean and how? I think it's better Image dimension based on the RowTemplate.Height property . Please recommend and advise from you

It appears that you have inserted the 28x28 PNG image into the ImageList with its default properties set. The image is resized and resampled based on the ColorDepth and ImageSize properties. As a result, the image becomes smaller and of lower quality.
You don't need to have the image in an ImageList. include it in your project's Resources to keep it as is and set the relevant Graphics properties that produce high-quality shrinking and transformation.
In your project's Properties, open the resources designer and drop the image. In the code, declare a class variable of type Bitmap and assign the image to it. Implement the grid's CellPainting event as follows...
Public Class Form1
    Private ReadOnly checkMarkImage As Bitmap

    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        checkMarkImage = My.Resources.CheckMark
    End Sub

   Private Sub DataGridView1_CellPainting(
       sender As Object,
       e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles _
       DataGridView1.CellPainting
       Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

       e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All)

       If e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso
           e.ColumnIndex < 0 AndAlso
           e.RowIndex <> DataGridView1.NewRowIndex AndAlso
           String.IsNullOrEmpty(dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText) Then
           Dim gs = e.Graphics.Save()
           Dim sz = DataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height - 4 ' Change as needed...
           Dim srcRect = New Rectangle(Point.Empty, checkMarkImage.Size)
           Dim destRect = New Rectangle(
               e.CellBounds.Right - sz - 1,
               e.CellBounds.Y + (e.CellBounds.Height - sz) \ 2,
               sz, sz)

           ' High-quality shrinking if needed...
           e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
           ' Note the white checkmark with and without this one...
           e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality
           e.Graphics.DrawImage(checkMarkImage, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
           e.Graphics.Restore(gs)
           e.Handled = True
       End If
   End Sub
End Class


Sorry I was late replying and your answer was perfect. Btw is it possible that I can set the position of the image for example like center/middle .

@dlaksmi Dim destRect = New Rectangle(e.CellBounds.X + (e.CellBounds.Width - sz) \ 2, e.CellBounds.Y + (e.CellBounds.Height - sz) \ 2, sz, sz)

Thanks for response. Sorry I'm Late reply
